# Any restrictions on development in Vista

Tags: iis, windows-vista

I'm looking at a new computer which will probably have vista on it.  But there are so many editions of vista; are there any weird restrictions on what you can run on the various editions?  For instance you couldn't run IIS on Windows ME.  Can you still run IIS on the home editions of vista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vista Home Basic only has enough IIS features to host WCF services and does not have any of web server features for hosting static files, asp.net, etc.

Here is a [link](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/compare-editions/default.aspx) to compare editions.  I would recommend going with Home Premium or Ultimate depending on whether the computer will run on a domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Aero on the 'basic' editions, and there are some 'extras' that only run in Ultimate.  You probably won't care about those for development, though.  The only thing to be careful of would be that it has the same client access restrictions that XP did.

Answer (score 0):

Get Home Premium unless you need to connect to a domain controller (if you don't know what that is, you don't need it).